# Powershell script to list Zip files in a Directory with their Size

Tags: list, powershell, directory, zip, size

I have came across a way to list Zip content in a Directory - I would like to include the file size information.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')
foreach($sourceFile in (Get-ChildItem -filter '*.zip'))
{
    [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($sourceFile.FullName).Entries.FullName |
            %{ "$sourcefile`:$_" }
}
```

Could someone help me to add size information - current display format is:

```
zipName:zipContentName
```

I would like to keep formatting as:

```
zipName:zipContentName:zipContentSize
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than looping through the FullNames, loop through the [entries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry(v=vs.110).aspx) themselves:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')
foreach($sourceFile in (Get-ChildItem -filter '*.zip'))
{
    [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($sourceFile.FullName).Entries |
            %{ "$sourcefile`:$($_.FullName):$($_.Length)";  }
}
```